# Cannot run python exe file after create with pyinstaller

Tags: python, selenium, pyinstaller

So I have this `python` project that using `argparse` library to accept `arguments`.
When I run the project using the `.py` file using this command:

```
python c:\projects\proj1\main.py --user blabla --password 12345678
```

All good.

Now I create `.exe` file using `pyinstaller` and this commend:

```
py_installer_path\pyinstaller.exe --onefile c:\projects\proj1\main.py
```

And when I try to run it:

```
c:\main.exe --user blabla --password 12345678
```

I received this error:

```
usage: main.exe [-h] -u USER -p PASSWORD
main.exe: error: the following arguments are required: -u/--user, -p/--password
```

**EDIT**

Ok so the problem is with `undetected_chromedriver`:

> File "undetected_chromedriver_*init*_.py", line 388, in **init**
> File "undetected_chromedriver\dprocess.py", line 37, in start_detached
> File "multiprocessing\connection.py", line 255, in recv   File
> "multiprocessing\connection.py", line 310, in _recv_bytes

This module is install on my `env` and as i mentioned this works fine when I run the script using the `.py` file.
Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

It is extremely hard to debug when missing the main code.
If it is sensitive code, just create a simple function that can work as a example.
It might also help you debug if you narrow it down to a few lines of code.